# Should answer obtained by Picard's iteration match that obtained by any other method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I have some problems regarding solutions of first order differential equations obtained by Picard's iteration and by other methods. Like this example: $y'=xy+1$, $y(0)=1$.

I applied Picard's iteration as follows:

$$\begin{align}
&y_1(x)=1+\int_0^x[1+t(1)]dt=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\\
&y_2(x)=1+\int_0^x\left[1+t\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\right]dt=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{8}\\
&y_3(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\frac{x^5}{15}+\frac{x^6}{48}\end{align}$$
and so on.

Now, I tried to solve it using integration factor $e^{-\int xdx}=e^{-x^2/2}$

Then, $$\begin{align}ye^{-x^2/2}& =\int e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&=\int1.e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&=e^{-x^2/2}\int1dx-\int\left(-xe^{-x^2/2}\int 1dx \right)dx\\
&=xe^{-x^2/2}+\int x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
&=xe^{-x^2/2}+e^{-x^2/2}\int x^2dx-\int\left(-xe^{-x^2/2}\int x^2dx \right)dx\\
&=xe^{-x^2/2}+\frac{x^3}{3}e^{-x^2/2}+\int \frac{x^4}{3}e^{-x^2/2}dx\end{align}$$

I am getting only odd powers of $x$ through these integrations. Why is that? Shouldn't both the answers match? Moreover, are the series obtained through the iterations always expansions of some function? I cannot identify such a 'function' here. And if not, how do I know the series converges?

Comment: The answers from the different methods will match due to the uniqueness of solutions of ODE's with given initial conditions, however different methods will give the answer in different forms and it may not be obvious how they are equal, this is because there will always be an infinite number of series which converge to any given number/function. For the examples you give you could try taylor expanding all the terms in the second method to see if you get the same series.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the initial value resp. that the indefinite integral contains an integration constant. If you start with
$$
ye^{-x^2/2}-1=\int_0^xe^{-t^2/2}dt
$$
then the right side gives, as observed, the odd degree terms. The initial condition gives an in the solution an additional term
$$
1·e^{x^2/2}=1+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{2·2^2}+\frac{x^6}{6·2^3}+…
$$
which are exactly the even order term of the power series.